# Excel, генерация случайных чисел с заданным процентом вероятности

Tags: excel, генерация-случайных-данных

Есть задача сделать массив случайных чисел из заданного по условию диапазона в большом объёме. (около тридцати тысяч ячеек) Проблема заключается в том, что для некоторых диапазонов чисел необходимо указать процентную вероятность выпадения. При поиске в гугле удалось обнаружить один из возможных способов с предварительным указанием вероятности для каждого отдельного числа. Способ весьма хороший и подошёл бы, если не факт того, что таких чисел в общем возможном диапазоне десять тысяч.

---

**Вопрос закрыт**, так как найден более удобный способ через с++
Спасибо за уделённое к теме внимание

Comment: Как насчет того, чтобы создать упорядоченный массив, диапазон за диапазоном с нужным количеством значений, а в конце просто его перетасовать случайным образом?

Answer (score 0):

Алгоритм, который можно реализовать на `VBA`

1. Задать вероятность каждого числа
2. Суммировать вероятности

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3. Вычислить % каждой вероятности относительно общей суммы:

   `=B2/$B$10`
4. Получить количество каждого числа в массиве:

   `=ОКРУГЛ(C2*1000;0)`
5. Создать массив с полученным общим количеством значений (зависит от множителя - 1000, 10 000...)
6. Заполнить массив числами в соответствии с их количеством.
7. В случайном порядке получить индексы и извлечь по этим индексам значения из массива

Comment: Vikktur, спасибо большое за ваш комментарий. К сожалению, такой способ не подходит. В теме описывал что вероятность необходимо проставить для десяти тысяч значений, а это слишком трудозатратный процесс. Возможно, есть какой-то способ указания вероятности конкретно для определённого диапазона чисел ([-45; -15] - 20%, [-15;0] - 40%, [0;30] - 60%, например (Непосредственно в моём условие, диапазон с тысячными числами, которых в общей сложности образуется десять тысяч)), но я его не смог найти. Если у Вас есть какие-то идеи на этот счёт, то буду весьма признателен за них :)